# "Я тоже" vs "мне тоже"

Tags: грамматика, местоимения

Sorry if this is a simple question but I'm struggling with when I should use these two and if they are interchangeable.

Comment: it's pretty much like me and I in English, also, there's no need to apologize it's indeed not that easy to grasp.  Also, as to me, this is not a duplicate but this can be helpful - http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/12309/%D0%AF-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8E-%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE

Comment: @shabunc thank you :) I get it's like "I" or "me" but "I too" makes no sense in english. (to my knowledge at least). Which is why I'm struggling when to use "I too" over "me too"

Comment: actually there's a famous poem, "I, too, sing America". It's indeed non-typical though - but ok, think of phrase "I also".

Comment: Can you provide the situation where you're going to use them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those two versions simply represent the pronoun **я** in two of six grammatical cases. Examples:

> -- Я хочу есть. -- **Я тоже** хочу (есть). (nominative)
>
> У сестры новый телефон. У **меня тоже** (новый). (genitive)
>
> Моему приятелю на том спектакле было скучно. **Мне тоже** (было
>   скучно). (dative)
>
> Моего коллегу послали в командировку. **Меня тоже** (послали).
>   (accusative)
>
> Родители гордятся моим старшим братом... и **мной тоже** (гордятся).
>   (instrumental)
>
> Ты не* будешь вспоминать об этом лете и **обо мне тоже** (не будешь вспоминать).
>   (prepositional)

*Note: in Russian **я тоже** can be used in both positive and *negative* clauses while in English a similar negation typically needs smth. like *neither* instead of *too* or *also*.

Answer (score 5):

The usage of я тоже and мне тоже confirming the previous sentence or that of the other partner in a conversation entirely **depends on the verb** meant and the case required. The pronoun can be used in different cases according to the situation.  To make it clear, consider the following.

> Я люблю гулять вечером,а ты?--Я тоже (meaning Я тоже люблю).You can't say мне.
>
> Мне нравится гулять вечером.--Мне тоже.(meaning мне тоже нравится).You can't say я.

The meaning is absolutely the same.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.